# Converting a list to a "two or more objects" argument in R

Tags: r, arguments

I have to call a function in R that takes "2 or more objects" as an input, so the function definition is:

`function(..., all = TRUE, <other named parameters>)`

where ... is defined as `2 or more objects`

The issue is I have is that my objects are in a list, and I am working with a different number of objects according to what I want to do. So if my list has 3 elements for example I would have to do:

`function(list[[1]], list [[2]], list[[3]])`

How can I do that generically, regardless of the number of element in my list ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use do.call, as that takes a list of arguments and applies them on function. Eg for rbind :

```
X <- list(A=1:3,B=4:6,C=7:9)
do.call(rbind,X)

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
A    1    2    3
B    4    5    6
C    7    8    9
```

Mind you, if you need extra arguments, you should add them to the list as well. See eg :

```
X <- list(A=list(A1=1:2,A2=3:4),B=list(B1=5:6,B2=7:8))

do.call(c,X)      # Returns a list
do.call(c,X,recursive=TRUE)  # Gives an error
do.call(c,c(X,list(recursive=TRUE)))

A.A11 A.A12 A.A21 A.A22 B.B11 B.B12 B.B21 B.B22 
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: You can pass recursive argument in one go. `do.call("c", list(X,recursive=TRUE))`. Quoting the function (here `c`) is a matter of preference.

Comment: In some cases, yes, but if `X` is a list of lists, this won't quite work.  It will work with an additional parameter `foo` with `c(X, foo=TRUE)` if `foo` is a scalar.  However, in this case the additional parameter, `recursive`, is a parameter for the `c` function, so Joris's way is perhaps the only way.  If the additional parameter is a vector, `c(X, foo=list(11:15))` will work.

Comment: @Aaron : I don't see what you're getting at. X is a list of lists in my example, and c(list1,list2) makes a list containing the elements of both lists, so that seems the desired behaviour in this case. Can you give an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: `ab <- list(a=1:3,b=4:6); c <- list(c=5:7)` Then compare `do.call(cbind, list(ab, c))` and `do.call(cbind, c(ab, c))`.

Comment: @Aaron : I see where the confusion comes from. `recursive` is here an extra argument to the c function, and should be concatenated to the original list using `c()`. In your example, you either call cbind on a list of lists, or on a list constructed by concatenating two lists. That's not in contradiction with what Roman says, in contrary. Main point is here that do.call has only two arguments : a function and a list. And the list is passed as arguments to the function.

Comment: I see I misread your comment; yes, using `c` as you suggest will work, but using `list` as Roman suggests may or may not.

Comment: @Aaron : ah, and I misread Roman's comment. You're right there.

Comment: To sum up, the main point I mean to add is that one has to be careful in constructing the parameter list so it has the proper arguments, especially when trying to combine two lists, especially as the lists resulting from `c` and `list` are different. In this case the result is the same because of the way `c` works when `recursive=TRUE`, but in other cases, one or the other may be desired.

Answer (score 6):

An example would be helpful, but I'm pretty sure you're looking for `do.call`:

```
do.call(function, c(list, list(all=TRUE, <other named parameters>)))
```